# Is this MB/s formula right ? python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was tring to do a mbps meter on my wget ripoff, after lots of try and error i stumbled upon this, which matches my download speed i just don't know if it's right because i don't have another conection with diferent download speed to test it on.

If anyone has a better way of doing it please tell me.

```
print("Downloading: [{}MB]{}...".format(str(size/1048576)[:4],file_name))
done = 0
old = time.time()
for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=65536):
    f.write(chunk)
    done += len(chunk)
    perc = done/size
    mbps = str((done/(time.time()-old))/1048576)[:4] #This line over here
    print("[{}][{}Mb/s]{}%".format(int(perc*50)*"="+" "*(50 - int(perc*50)),mbps,int(perc*100)),end="\r")
f.close()
```

Comment: Yes, that's fine.

Comment: @TimRoberts Alright thank you.